# How to disable cache prefetching on AMD family 17h CPUs?

Tags: performance, x86, amd-processor

Is there a way to disable cache prefetching on AMD family 17h CPUs?

On family 10h CPUs, this is possible by setting a bit in MSRC001_1022 ([programmatically disable hardware prefetching on AMD systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275587/programmatically-disable-hardware-prefetching-on-amd-systems?noredirect=1&lq=1)). This MSR is not available on family 17h CPUs (https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56255_3_03.PDF).

Comment: That MSR still exists in family 16h, it is documented in the BIOS and Kernel PR. There isn't such a document for the family 17h, maybe because it is not needed. Have you tried read/writing it?

Comment: Yes, there is such an MSR that is set to 0x500000 by default on my system. Setting it to 0x502000 (i.e., setting bit 13 to 1) doesn't seem to make a difference with respect to prefetching.