# Is gcc's -march=native a convenience option? Is there magic you can't get manually?

Tags: gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, compiler-optimization, compiler-options

When using gcc's `-march=native` option it sets a number of flags/options,
but could this be replicated by setting everything manually, or are there things which are set that are not exposed to the user when doing so manually?

By replicated I mean could you set everything yourself without `native` and produce the same binary, given of course you are allowed to specify the microarchitecture with `-march`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `gcc -v -march=native foo.c`, the options passed to the actual C to asm compiler (`cc1`) don't include "native", only an arch/tune and some cache-size parameters.  **So yes, you could pass the same options to a cross-compiler and not be missing out on anything.**  I don't know how much effect that cache-size options have, perhaps on loop thresholds for using NT stores if it ever does that for some targets.

And explicit `-mabc` `-mno-xyz` options for every ISA extension GCC knows about, so it can optimize e.g. for a VM where CPUID doesn't expose some features, or for Pentium/Celeron before Ice Lake without AVX/FMA/BMI extensions, or Ice Lake Pentium / Celeron which lack AVX-512, unlike `-march=icelake-client`

I've manually line-wrapped the terminal output from x86-64 GCC on GNU/Arch Linux:

```
$ gcc -v -march=native spawn.c
...
gcc version 13.2.1 20230801 (GCC) 
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-march=native' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/cc1 -quiet -v spawn.c -march=skylake  \
-mmmx mpopcnt -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mavx -mavx2 -mno-sse4a \
-mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mfma -mno-avx512f -mbmi -mbmi2 -maes -mpclmul -mno-avx512vl \
-mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512pf -mno-avx512vbmi \
-mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx5124vnniw -mno-avx5124fmaps -mno-avx512vpopcntdq -mno-avx512vbmi2\
-mno-gfni -mno-vpclmulqdq -mno-avx512vnni -mno-avx512bitalg -mno-avx512bf16 \
-mno-avx512vp2intersect -mno-3dnow -madx -mabm -mno-cldemote -mclflushopt -mno-clwb \
-mno-clzero -mcx16 -mno-enqcmd  -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mfxsr -mno-hle -msahf -mno-lwp -mlzcnt\
-mmovbe -mno-movdir64b -mno-movdiri -mno-mwaitx -mno-pconfig -mno-pku -mno-prefetchwt1 \
-mprfchw -mno-ptwrite -mno-rdpid -mrdrnd -mrdseed -mno-rtm -mno-serialize -msgx -mno-sha \
-mno-shstk -mno-tbm -mno-tsxldtrk -mno-vaes -mno-waitpkg -mno-wbnoinvd -mxsave -mxsavec \
-mxsaveopt -mxsaves -mno-amx-tile -mno-amx-int8 -mno-amx-bf16 -mno-uintr -mno-hreset \
-mno-kl -mno-widekl -mno-avxvnni -mno-avx512fp16 -mno-avxifma -mno-avxvnniint8 \
-mno-avxneconvert -mno-cmpccxadd -mno-amx-fp16 -mno-prefetchi -mno-raoint \
-mno-amx-complex \
\
--param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 \
--param l2-cache-size=8192 -mtune=skylake \
-quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase spawn.c -dumpbase-ext .c -version -o /tmp/ccj4afQ8.s
...
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccb6usSK.o /tmp/ccj4afQ8.s
...
```

So "native" is still there in the environment, but I don't expect `cc1` pulls it out.  All the `-m` options between `-mmmx` and `-mno-amx-complex` are Intel and AMD ISA extensions my i7-6700k CPU does/doesn't have.  So the `-march=skylake` passed to `cc1` is probably redundant; everything it sets is overridden by `-m` feature options and `-mtune=skylake`.

In the last couple lines of options with `--param`, 8192 KiB is actually the size of the L3 last-level cache on my i7-6700k (4c8t).  When this part of GCC was designed, the last-level shared cache typically was L2, but three levels of cache are common these days (with two levels of per-core private cache, so cache-blocking for L2 size could be reasonable in some cases.)  So anyway, presumably nobody bothered to rename the option to `llc-size`, and the way it's used for tuning heuristics by `cc1` / `cc1plus` works if the `gcc` "driver" front-end just passes the last-level cache size.

Skylake has 32 KiB L1d and 32 KiB L1i caches.  Line size is 64 bytes in all levels.  (L2 has a "spatial prefetcher" that likes to complete an aligned pair of lines, so there's [a weak behaviour a bit like a 128-byte line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126606/should-the-cache-padding-size-of-x86-64-be-128-bytes) there).

Presumably `-mtune=skylake` has unrolling and inlining heuristics appropriate for the known I-cache / uop-cache sizes, and `--param l1-cache-size=32` is based on L1d.  Sizes are different on some CPUs like Ice Lake and Alder Lake P-cores (48K L1d / 32K L1i) have different sizes, or Zen 1 had 32K L1d / 64K L1i.

---

#### LTO is similar, I think

I only see `--param l1-cache-size=32` and other cache options getting passed to `cc1` (the C to GIMPLE + asm compiler), not to `lto1` (GIMPLE to asm re-optimizer).  I suspect they're not very important, and IDK if anything in modern GCC still depends on them, at least for x86.

More options get passed via the environment in `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=` which still includes the original command-line args at the end.  So `-march=native` is in there, after the `-march=skylake -mabc -mno-xyz -mtune=skylake` options.  But invocation of `lto1` *doesn't* include that, it stops after `-mtune=skylake`, so I think the actual LTO optimization pass of `-flto` is still fully controlled by its command line, not the machine it's running on.

Comment: Thank you. Guess my inexperience with gcc shows when the output is right there with verbose.

Comment: @Xavanteex: It's something I'd been wondering about for a while, too, but having a place to share the answer made it worthwhile to look and see, so thanks for posting the question.  I suspected it was just arch/tune and some cache-parameter stuff since I'd noticed that before, but I hadn't noticed last time I looked that `cc1` didn't get any `=native` options which mostly rules out any additional differences.