# In FreeBSD, how can I disable hardware prefetching?

Tags: kernel, freebsd, prefetch

I just finished reading 
[How to Choose between Hardware and Software Prefetch on 32-Bit Intel® Architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-choose-between-hardware-and-software-prefetch-on-32-bit-intel-architecture/)
 and made the decision that I need to disable hardware prefetching for my use case.

In particular the following applies exactly to me:

> Generally, prefer software-controlled prefetch in situations where all the following are true: irregular access patterns are present, short arrays must be prefetched, and making changes to existing application code is acceptable.

I found a number of answers that reference Linux specifically [(see this SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784041/how-do-i-programatically-disable-hardware-prefetching).  However, for performance reasons I am using FreeBSD.

Even if this ends up being a bad idea, I want to benchmark by application without h/w prefetching.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to do the same using [cpucontrol](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?cpucontrol) command?