# How to test prefetchers are disabled or not in Intel core i7?

Tags: c++, intel, performancecounter, perf, prefetch

I disabled the hardware prefetcher as follows:

```
#sudo wrmsr  0x1a4 15
```

Each bit 1 indicates it is disabled as per document..
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors.

But i dint feel any difference while I am running the programs. How can I cross check they are really disabled? Any easy ways to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You won't "feel" it, you need to measure various CPU intensive workloads. Try rendering some video clips with it enabled and with it disabled.

Comment: The easiest thing to benchmark is probably a memcpy loop.  Or maybe `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=32M count=1000`.  The large block-size means the memcpy that happens inside the `read(2)` system call won't just keep re-writing already-cached memory.  You'll see the higher throughput with a block-size like `128k` (half L2 size, but still big enough to not have too many system calls).  The `write(2)` to /dev/null doesn't touch the buffer, BTW.  The "driver" behind /dev/null just returns without touching the data.

Comment: @doug65536 "feel" means observe..!! i tried to see difference in time taken (using rdstc).. But even after disabling the time shows the same instead of increasing.!! Thanks for ur suggestion abt video clips..

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks u. But Im really sorry that I dint understand clearly, because I'm naive with OS also.  Can you be more clear how to do that and how to find out prefetcher disabled or not??

Comment: Maybe you processor only support disabling the prefetcher in the Bios http://stackoverflow.com/a/21383108/116388

Comment: Better put your measurement code, people often do things like trying to measure a single access instead of amortizing, or using bad alignment.